# How to make a Custom List with sheet cross reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

At the end of the month i get a excel file with a variable number of sheets.

Every sheet has a value in the same cell: `A1`

I want to create a new sheet and display all the values of A1 on every sheet and the sum.

I know how to get the value of a cross sheet cell `=Sheet1!A1` but if i put in a new sheet `=Sheet1!A1` and try to extent as a series it will fill the formula with `=Sheet1!`**B**`1` instead of `=Sheet`**2**`!A1` which is the desire result.

How can I make a custom list with sheet cross reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how you'd like to do this, a simple way would be to use an indirect

So on your summary, if you start in row 1 -

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!$A$1")
```

That will show A1 on Sheet1

Row 2 will show A1 on Sheet2

etc.

---

Another way to approach it would be with a macro

```
Sub gather()
Dim wssrc As Worksheet
 'if this stays as activesheet, only run this when summary sheet is active
 'Otherwise, just change the activesheet to the summary sheet like -
 'Set wssrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4") where "Sheet4" is whatever your summary sheet is
 Set wssrc = ActiveSheet
 Dim i As Integer
 i = 1

   For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      If Not sh.Name = wssrc.Name Then
       wssrc.Cells(i, 1) = sh.Cells(1, 1)
       i = i + 1
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

This iterates through all of the sheets in the workbook, checks to make sure they aren't your summary sheet, and copy their `A1` value to the summary sheet in column A.

Comment: Excellent. Just a note about the formula, if you can't start in row 1, you can adjust it by subtracting how many rows it is from 1 to where you start. This will make the the row number adjust to the sheet numbers.